# When to use a Bind shell vs. a Reverse shell?

Tags: metasploit

Metasploit question:-

I know what these shells are but am a little confused on the execution.

Assuming that you successfully get a meterpreter shell and want to upload a backdoor, what should you use as a payload in the backdoor file- should I use a TCP Bind shell or a TCP Reverse shell?

And, if I use Bind shell then what do I have to do to execute this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bind tcp opens up a port on the victim's device. Usually a machine is behind a firewall (or NAT) and firewalls don't allow ports other than a few specific ones (like 80, 443, 22, etc). Reverse TCP tries to connect to you (from the target machine back to you: you open a port and wait for the connection). The attacking machine (yours) has a listener port on which it receives the connection, after which, code or command execution is achieved. If it is remotely, port forwarding should be done on your router.

Comment: HI thanks for answering, in reverse TCP it is very much easy to get the victim to connect to us. But forex, I am using bind TCP now how can I connect to the victim?

Comment: Just connect to that port on its computer with something like netcat. nc <victim ip> <port> where port is the one you specified while creating bind tcp shellcode